# SFTP PHP 5.6 using phpseclib hangs

Tags: php, xampp, sftp, phpseclib

I'm trying a simple example

```
$sftp = new phpseclib\Net\SFTP(FTP_ADDRESS);
if (!$sftp->login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS)) {
    $logger->error("FTP credentials error");
    $logger->error($sftp->getLastSFTPError());
} else {
    $logger->log("Connection successful");
}

  print_r($sftp->rawlist());
```

However the script just hangs and finally times out

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\XookCatalogFeed\lib\phpseclib\Net\SSH2.php on line 3186
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.2015  152184  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.2244  2275600 handle ( )  ..\index.php:95
3   0.2246  2276880 {closure:C:\xampp\htdocs\XookCatalogFeed\handlers\import.php:157-285}( )    ..\index.php:95
4   0.2254  2303944 phpseclib\Net\SFTP->login( )    ..\import.php:170
5   5.1277  4457272 phpseclib\Net\SFTP->_send_sftp_packet( )    ..\SFTP.php:444
6   5.1278  4457592 phpseclib\Net\SSH2->_send_channel_packet( ) ..\SFTP.php:2635
7   30.0009 4457760 phpseclib\Net\SSH2->_send_binary_packet( )  ..\SSH2.php:3332
```

I have tried a lot of stuff but nothing seems to work. I have done some debugging (step by step) it looks like the servers accepts thje credential but then the client just loops sending empty data at _send_binary_packet.

Here is the log: https://gist.github.com/vlopez/2a48d261ab7713dbc06d

Someone, please help.

Comment: Can you connect to the same SFTP server using the same credentials using any GUI SFTP client (WinSCP for instance)? Can out include its log to your question?

Comment: Seems like https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/711 might be relevant.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to connect using Filezilla or Putty SFTP

Comment: Can out include FileZilla log to your question? I mean the log, not the message list.

Comment: Looks like it's due to PHP's not supporting unsigned integers: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/711#issuecomment-115105465 The fix appears to be to convert the number to a float.